# Youtube embed looks fine in WP editor but oversize in preview page

Tags: wordpress, youtube, embed, block

I have this problem where I embed a YT video in the wordpress editor, where it populates and looks fine, but when I check the preview page of the post the video is square and oversized.

This is the view from the editor where it looks normal.

[in editor view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJcBA.jpg)

This is the view of the video when I check the Preview page.

[how it appears on preview page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QM6wR.jpg)

These two views are when using the YT embed block. I tried using the code block and pasting in YT embed code for the video, but that just resulted in the embed code showing on the preview page.

Any advice on how I can fix this to make the video show as normal would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned blocks I'm guessing you're using the Gutenberg editor from Wordpress. To display responsive embeds your theme need to support them. You need to add the following to your `function.php`.

> The embed blocks automatically apply styles to embedded content to
> reflect the aspect ratio of content that is embedded in an iFrame.

```
<?php
if ( ! function_exists( 'theme_supports' ) ) {
  add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_supports' );
  function theme_supports() {
    add_theme_support( 'responsive-embeds' );
  };
}; ?>
```

---

### Learn more

- Theme Support @ https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/themes/theme-support/